# How to get data from table to variable with select in event?

Tags: mysql

I have the event

```
CREATE EVENT `start_insert_record_to_inout` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND STARTS '2014-07-12 12:07:00'
        ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
        ENABLE
        COMMENT 'comment'
        DO BEGIN    
        DECLARE `_count` INT DEFAULT 0; 
        DECLARE `_done` INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET _done = 1;   
        SELECT `count` INTO `_count` 
        FROM state_execution
        WHERE name = 'insert_record_to_inout' AND `type` = 'event'
        LIMIT 1;    

        -- AND `type` = 'event';
        IF _done THEN 
            INSERT INTO state_execution (`name`, `type`, `isUsed`,`count`) VALUES ('insert_record_to_inout', 'event','0',0);        
        END IF; 

        IF `_count` < 50 THEN

            IF _done THEN 
                SET `_count` = 1;
                SET _done = 0;
            ELSE 
                SET `_count` = `_count` + 1;
            END IF;
            UPDATE state_execution SET `count` = `_count` 
            WHERE name = 'insert_record_to_inout' AND `type` = 'event';

            call insert_record_to_inout();

            SELECT `count` INTO `_count` 
            FROM state_execution
            WHERE name = 'insert_record_to_inout' AND `type` = 'event'
            LIMIT 1;

            IF _done THEN 
                SET `_count` = 0;
            ELSE 
                SET `_count` = `_count` - 1;
            END IF;     
            UPDATE state_execution SET `count` = `_count` WHERE name = 'insert_record_to_inout' AND `type` = 'event';

        END IF; 
END
```

But  this code

```
SELECT `count` INTO `_count` 
FROM state_execution
WHERE name = 'insert_record_to_inout' AND `type` = 'event'
LIMIT 1;
```

not working. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Does it work when you just execute the query?